# How to form an OR choice in Parsec that may match many options, but must match at least one option?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm trying to write a parser in Haskell using the Parsec package. One part of the rules for the input requires the parser to match an option of rules. Out of the rules more than one rule may be match, but *at least* one rule must match or the parser is expected to produce an error.

Let me provide an example. Assume we have two Parsec rules named `first` and `more`. It is possible that:

- the input matches `first` followed by `more`;
- the input matches only `first`; or that
- the input matches only `more`.

In any case, at least one of `first` or `more` must match. Any ideas on how to do this? I thought about using the `<|>` but if I understand it correctly it will only match *one* of the rules (i.e. the first one that is successful).

**EDIT:**

Clarification: If both `first` and `more` matches, the result of both must be returned. If only one matches, the returned value of the other can be some null value like `Nothing`, but it is not allowed to return `Nothing` for both `first` and `more`.

Comment: Do you mean that the same input could be parsed by `first` and by `more`, and you want both results returned?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes, exactly. Updated the question.

Comment: I'd like to clarify one more time. When you say "both `first` and `more` match", do you mean `first >> more` matches, or `first` matches starting at this position and `more` matches starting at this position?

Comment: @DanielWagner: I mean both matches in the sense of `first >> more`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the things should come is some particular order:

```
atLeastOne :: [Parser a] -> Parser [a]
atLeastOne ps = do
  rs <- catMaybes <$> mapM optionMaybe ps
  if null rs
    then parserFail "At least one thing should be present"
    else return rs
```

Comment: This seems to be the most idiomatic way of doing it. =)

Answer (score 1):

The really naive way is like this:

```
oneOrBoth first_ more_ = try both <|> first <|> more where
    first = (:[]) <$> first_
    more  = (:[]) <$> more_
    both  = liftM2 (++) first more
```

This will produce a list of length either one or two, with a preference for producing a list of length two when that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as general as the other answers, but this would solve your problem:

```
atLeastOne :: ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m (Maybe a, Maybe b)
atLeastOne p1 p2 = firstMatches <|> secondMatches <|> fail "Invalid input"
    where
        firstMatches = do
            a <- p1
            maybeB <- (p2 >>= Just <|> return Nothing)
            return (Just a, maybeB)
        secondMatches = do
            b <- p2
            return (Nothing, Just b)
```

Usage:

```
atLeastOne first more
```

**LATER EDIT:**

Or a more type-safe version:

```
data Choice3 a b c = Choice1Of3 a | Choice2Of3 b | Choice3Of3 c

atLeastOne :: ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m b -> ParsecT s u m (Choice1Of3 a b (a, b))
atLeastOne p1 p2 = firstMatches <|> secondMatches <|> fail "Invalid input"
    where
        firstMatches = do
            a <- p1
            (p2 >>= \b -> Choice3Of3 (a, b)) <|> Choice1Of3 a
        secondMatches = do
            b <- p2
            return $ Choice2Of3 b
```